# SSH remote command with nohup not working as expected

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, script, nohup

I wanted to run a long running command in a remote server, even after the connection terminates. So I thought of using `ssh host "nohup cmd &"`. But for some reason, neither cmd is going to background, nor it's output are redirected to nohup.out. Everything is happening as if I ran just `ssh host cmd`.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ssh utubuntu16x64-1 "nohup ls &"
bin
scripts
views
workflows
```

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ssh utubuntu16x64-1 "ls"
bin
scripts
views
workflows
```

I tried running command `nohup cmd &` directly in remote machine, and it is working properly. I'm not getting where the error is.

Answer (score 3):

The [specification of `nohup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/nohup.html) states [emphasis mine]:

> **If standard input is associated with a terminal**, the `nohup` utility **may** redirect standard input from an unspecified file.
>
> **If the standard output is a terminal**, all output written by the named utility to its standard output **shall** be appended to the end of the file `nohup.out` in the current directory. […]
>
> **If standard error is a terminal** and standard output is open but is not a terminal, all output written by the named utility to its standard error **shall** be redirected to the same open file description as the standard output. **If standard error is a terminal** and standard output either is a terminal or is closed, the same output **shall** instead be appended to the end of the `nohup.out` file as described above.

Although it does not specify the behavior of `nohup` regarding standard I/O streams that point to non-terminals, a sane expectation is `nohup` shall leave them as they are. `nohup` redirects a standard I/O stream if it's a terminal, not if it's anything else. The job of `nohup` consists of two parts:

1. ignore SIGHUP,
2. redirect away from a **terminal**.

Your `ssh utubuntu16x64-1 "nohup ls &"` does not allocate a terminal on the remote side. The standard I/O streams are pipes connecting the remote command to the respective I/O streams of the local `ssh` (except stdin in this particular case, keep reading). None of them is a terminal, so `nohup` does not redirect them.

There are at least two methods to cause redirection to (remote) `nohup.out`:

1. Allocate a tty on the remote side:

   ```
   ssh -t utubuntu16x64-1 "nohup ls &"
   ```

   (If the local stdin is not a terminal then you need `-tt`.) There may be side effects though (e.g. a local message saying `Connection to utubuntu16x64-1 closed.`).
2. Redirect manually:

   ```
   ssh utubuntu16x64-1 "nohup ls >nohup.out 2>&1 &"
   ```

Note that ["may" differs from "shall"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap01.html#tag_01_05). Even if the remote standard input is a terminal, `nohup` may or may not redirect it away. In general not redirecting input may make a difference, but here [`&` assigns stdin to `/dev/null` (or to an equivalent file)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02) in the first place, so `nohup` finds its stdin not associated with a terminal anyway.

Both methods shall [make the local `ssh` not wait](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346549/108618).

---

> I tried running command `nohup cmd &` directly in remote machine, and it is working properly.

"Directly" or after sole `ssh utubuntu16x64` you are in an interactive shell and there is a tty allocated for it, all the standard I/O streams are associated with the tty. This is the reason your `nohup` worked as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

`nohup` expecting no output to stdout and stderr to be able to run in background via ssh.

in your case, here is the correct syntax:

```
ssh user@host "nohup cmd > nohup.out 2>&1 &"
```